# Why were France awarded penalty during the last minute maul against England?

Tags: rugby-union

With England driving a maul toward France's touchline, the referee awarded a penalty to France which cost England a potential try and the Six Nations title.

What infringement did England make for him to make this call?

Answer (score 2):

The indication from Nigel Owens was that the English players arriving at the breakdown had gone off their feet.  The explanation being that the maul had ended and a ruck had formed and players need to remain on their feet.

Watching live I felt that the penalty should have gone to England for the French players not releasing the tackled player and the ball.